# Pandas: what kind of join is this? or is it a join?

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to update `df` A with B to produce C.

A =

```
Name   city 
bob    a
adam   b
mike   c
fred   d
```

B =

```
Name   city
adam   e
mike   f
```

C =

```
Name   city
bob    a
adam   e
mike   f
fred   d
```

maybe a join is not necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
B.set_index('Name').combine_first(A.set_index('Name')).reset_index()
Out: 
   Name city
0  adam    e
1   bob    a
2  fred    d
3  mike    f
```

Comment: Dagnabbit!   Beat me too it.  I had the exact same solution.

Comment: @ScottBoston A little verbose though :)